# i am getting java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to check internetConnection?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

this is the error i am getting

```
03-25 12:11:15.019  21907-21907/np.com.tester.wlms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: np.com.tester.wlms, PID: 21907
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{np.com.tester.wlms/np.com.tester.wlms.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at np.com.tester.wlms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my internetConnectionCheck.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


public class InternetConnectionCheck extends ActionBarActivity{
    public boolean isInternetOn()   //checking internet for connection
    {
        ConnectivityManager con = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = con.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            // MESSAGE TO SCREEN FOR TESTING (IF REQ)
            //Toast.makeText(this, connectionType + ” connected”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

this is the MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     private InternetConnectionCheck internetConnectionCheck;
     private  String internetCheck;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        internetCheck=String.valueOf(internetConnectionCheck.isInternetOn());

         Toast.makeText(this,internetCheck, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    }



}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 private InternetConnectionCheck internetConnectionCheck;
```

in connection with the call here

```
internetConnectionCheck.isInternetOn()
```

`InternetConnectionCheck` is your object and you define the variable name `internetConnectionCheck` for it. But you never ever initialize the object with something. Therefore its just null. As soon as you call the method `.isInternetOn()` you will always receive the `NullPointerException`. If you want to fix this, you need to create an instance of your object.

```
private InternetConnectionCheck internetConnectionCheck = new InternetConnectionCheck();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create instance of `InternetConnectionCheck` .

Otherwise `isInternetOn` must be static method

```
public statis boolean isInternetOn()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Utility {
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


//Use it in your activity
boolean connected = Utility.isNetworkAvailable(this);
```

Comment: thank you so much for such a quick reply and solution works :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that InternetConnectionCheck  is not initialize that why you are getting null exception.

Try this

**internetConnectionCheck.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


public class InternetConnectionCheck extends ActionBarActivity{
    public static  boolean isInternetOn()   //checking internet for connection
    {
        ConnectivityManager con = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = con.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            // MESSAGE TO SCREEN FOR TESTING (IF REQ)
            //Toast.makeText(this, connectionType + ” connected”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
 }
 }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     private InternetConnectionCheck internetConnectionCheck;
     private  String internetCheck;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        internetCheck=String.valueOf(InternetConnectionCheck.isInternetOn());

         Toast.makeText(this,internetCheck, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    }



}
```